# restrictive subclass type hinting

Tags: python, pycharm, subclass, type-hinting, python-typing

I would like typehint a function such that it only accepts a type of a subclass of Foo and returns an instance of that subclass, rather than a different subclass:

```
class Foo:
        pass


class Bar(Foo):
    pass


class Baz(Foo):
    pass


class Spam:
    pass


def func(t):
    return t()


x: Bar = func(Bar)
y: Baz = func(Bar)  # disallowed
func(Spam)          # disallowed
```

The closest attempt I have is:

```
T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=Foo)


def func(t: typing.Type[T]) -> T:
    return t()
```

However lets say the function is more complicated and results in:

```
def func(t: typing.Type[T]) -> T:
    return Baz()
```

I would like the above to error, but it doesnt

Comment: That type *should* work; `mypy` 0.961 rejects `Baz()` as a valid return value of type `T`.

Comment: the type hint is not enforcable in any event. presumably you mean to be picked up by a linter or throw an error in the code ?

Comment: How are you expecting it to error? In a static type checker (e.g. `mypy`)? Or are you expecting a runtime error (which is not how `typing` works in Python)?

Answer (score 0):

Just to basically sum up and expand a little on the comments to your question:

That proposed annotation of yours does exactly what you described:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="Foo")
...

def func(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    ...
```

I.e. `t` must be the class `Foo` or any subclass of `Foo` and the output will be an instance of the class provided as an argument for `t`.

This means that the following should be picked up by a static type checker as *wrong*, regardless of what kind of class `Baz` is:

```py
...
def func(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    return Baz()
```

Returning a `Baz` object without consideration for `t` breaks the aforementioned contract.

And indeed, `mypy` states the following referring to the `return` statement:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Baz", expected "T")  [return-value]
```

Since this all works as expected, it is not clear what you mean, when you say this:

> I would like the above to error, but it doesn't

---

Now, this is all relevant to static type checkers *only*. Python, being what it is (i.e. dynamically typed), could not care less and happily allows you to return whatever object you desire from `func` as well as call that function with any argument you want.

If you want errors to be *raised* by the Python interpreter, you will have to add some runtime type checking logic to your code yourself. For example:

```py
...
def func(t: Type[T]) -> T:
    if not isinstance(t, type) or not issubclass(t, Foo):
        raise TypeError(f"{t} is not a subclass of `Foo`")
    return t()
```